# Eclipse error in Ubuntu (Quick Post Mortem)

Tags: android, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse IDE for Linux 64 bit and when I opened the IDE I ran into the following exception from the console.

```
"while attempting to get adb version /home/varun/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools/adb is not a file or directory"
```

Then I read in a forum that I need to type the following in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

After typing this, several packages were downloaded and installed in my machine and when i restarted my eclipse it did not give my any exceptions.

But my question is what did I do for me to resolve this issue ?.

If someone can tell me what that command did in a nutshell, it would help me to understand as to what was the issue and how it got resolved.
Also in that original thread there was not much explanation regarding this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it appears to be a 64bit package, it actually still relies on 32bit libraries in its core. Your unbutu installation did not have these libraries present and that is why your eclipse died on startup while loading the ADT plugin. 
Installing these libraries, which is what the statement is for, solved the issue.